# Utilizing map of struct from a class

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, struct

I have a shape object in my program that is to be placed in 3d space. The properties of the shape look like the following:

```
struct Shape{
Vector3 position, 
TYPE shapeType,
std::string resourcePath
};
```

**XmlReader**

```
map<Shape, Vector3> locations;

//Add pairs to map by reading from xml file, for eg:
//Initializing struct
Shape _shape = {
node->getPosition(), //position of the card in xml
node->getType(),
node->getPath()
}
//Add to map
```

The `map` above is a public field in my XmlReader class and in my main program, I'll iterate through the map to put the shapes in space.
In this case, I would have to initialize a `struct` in my main program as well to get the position and shape out of the map.
For eg:
In the map iterator,

```
for(std::map<Shape, Vector3>::iterator itr=locations.begin();itr!location.end();++itr)
Shape _Receivedshape = itr->first;
std::string resulttring = _Receivedshape.resourcePath;
```

Is the above a correct implementation to use since I am initializing the structure in my main program as well. If not, what would be a better implementation to use here?

Comment: Are you trying to get a *specific* Vector3 from the map given an external shape key? or are you just wanting to walk through the map and pull out the shape-key's resource path? (and note: you don't need the intermediate copy; just use `itr->first.resourcePath`. it should be valid since the iterator is valid).

Comment: @WhozCraig : I basically want to walk through a `map` and get all the properties of the `Shape` out in the main program (not only shape's resource path) So there would be additional lines saying `itr->first.Vector3` etc.

Comment: anything in particular you're doing with these shape keys? Is it something you can do using a for_each construct ? If you're not familiar with them, they're easy to code, and very efficient.

Comment: Actually not, thanks for the hint. I'll look them up. for_each is available in vectors as well?

Comment: `for_each` is available for any sequenced container in the std library. Another alternative would be to slurp the keys (your shapes) into an outer vector, then work with the vector, leaving the map untouched. But your code looks correct if you want to access the *key* for each element in your map. The only thing I would caution you against is *changing* the key held in the map. If you need to change something that may alter the key evaluation ordering, you can't do it while it is in the map; make a copy and use that.

Comment: `_Receivedshape` is a "reserved identifier", you shouldn't use it.